# How to create unchangeable part of html even though the browser's current urls changed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, css

I have searched about that for very long time. But I havn't known how it works and how to create it. I am so serious to get it. I am a beginner of Ajax and JQuery. I wish to create a fixed mp3 music player in my web. Although I have some code and know how to do mp3 player for html5, but I have not knew how to do fixed mp3 player which won't change playing when another pages load. Could you help me, please. Example: it is like of www.revernation.com and facebook's chat popup box, still active without refreshing another pages.

Comment: It would have to be in its own window, or use AJAX.

Comment: You can manipulate the URL-History with JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history. This is how soundcloud.com works. It's a single page website.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with history. I think OP wants to have mp3 player still going even when URL changes.

Comment: Thanks ! but I just want to get some part of page that won't change even if current url changed. eg, when going to profile page from home page in facebook, popup chat box still alive. I want to create that with php, ajax, jquery, css. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep an mp3 player running when the user navigates to a completely different site in the same browser window.

You can however keep the current page open and fake navigation to other subpages of your own site with History API + AJAX and DOM manipulation. The trick is sometimes called **pjax**.

An example implementation: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js does what is described in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is convert your app into an SPA.

> Single-Page Applications (SPAs) are Web apps that load a single HTML
>   page and dynamically update that page as the user interacts with the
>   app. SPAs use AJAX and HTML5 to create fluid and responsive Web apps,
>   without constant page reloads. However, this means much of the work
>   happens on the client side, in JavaScript.

### Best for SPA

i suggest you to go with AngularJS.

You can still do it with JQuery with Ajax calls if you don't want to use other front-end frameworks